# How to query ManyToMany field using current user in django?

Tags: python, django

In my django app I have a Message Model with a sender (User) and some receivers (also Users).
I want to display in a ListView, all messages that have the current logged user as one of its receivers (the current user must be in the receivers ManyToMany)
How to I do that?
Here is my code:

```
class MessageModel(models.Model):

    MESSAGE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'borrador'),
        ('new', 'nuevo'),
        ('red', 'leido'),
        ('deleted', 'borrado'),
    )

    subject = models.CharField(verbose_name="Asunto",max_length=50)
    
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                   related_name='+', verbose_name='destinatario', editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    receivers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="destinatarios")
    
    received_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Fecha" ,auto_now_add=True)
        
    state = models.CharField( verbose_name="Estado", max_length=50,blank=False, null=False, choices=MESSAGE_TYPE_CHOICES, default="new")

    message_body = models.TextField(verbose_name="Mensaje")

    @property
    def get_receivers(self):
        return self.receivers.all()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Mensaje"
        verbose_name_plural = "Mensajes"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject


class MailboxListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = MessageModel
    template_name = 'mailapp/inbox.html'
    context_object_name = 'messages'

    
    def get_queryset(self):
       # here i want to get only the messages in wich the current user is a receiver
        query_result = MessageModel.objects.all().order_by('received_date')

        return query_result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 def get_queryset(self):
       # here i want to get only the messages in wich the current user is a receiver
        query_result = MessageModel.objects.filter(receivers=self.request.user
).order_by('received_date')
```